# Howto refer to (or avoid) a numbered entity in section title

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing

In a master thesis, I need to refer to a model described elsewhere, from a section title, like

```
\section{Analysis of model X}
```

One way of referring to a model is to create a new counter, and then write

```
\section{Analysis of \cref{grandmodelofeverything}}
```

But now `hyperref` will complain because of invalid token, and it does not look good in the TOC either, especially since the titles of the sections the describe the models are more descriptive than

```
\section{Model 1}
```

They are currently like

```
\section{Adding the effect from Y processes}
```

Do I need to invent semi-descriptive long names like "The model by Authors with this modification" or can I live with these quirks?

Comment: @what The `hyperref`part is just a detail. The question is more about appropriate headers. I guess that the `hyperref` warning can be interpreted as "this is bad style" [putting reference in header].

Answer (score 0):

I chose to add the model name after the section title. That is

```
\section{The Grand Model of Everything (Model A)}
```

This they the table of contents become self-contained, and I can easily refer to different models from the text.